# Flyway mysqldump script Failing SILENTLY

Tags: mysql, flyway

A few updates

I've got a sql script migration that will run if I pipe it to mysql, but not via flyway. The script is being executed, but the first lines are apparently erroring out.

As soon as it encounters any line like this:
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = latin1 */ ;

The script silently stops functioning.  I've used simple insert statements to ensure the script is at least started, and it is.

I'm not trying to run mysql statements against a different type of database or anything. My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.cpt.migrations</groupId>
  <artifactId>cpt_migrations</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>cpt_migrations</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
              <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <user>root</user>
                  <password></password>
                  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cpt</url>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Running: 
`mvn clean compile flyway:clean flyway:migrate --debug --offline -ff -e`

Nets only this for the second migration:

```
[DEBUG] Locking table `cpt`.`schema_version`...
[DEBUG] Lock acquired for table `cpt`.`schema_version`
[INFO] Migrating schema `cpt` to version 2
[DEBUG] Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `cpt` to version 2
[DEBUG] Finished migrating schema `cpt` to version 2 (execution time 00:00.003s)
[DEBUG] MetaData table `cpt`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
[DEBUG] Unlocking table `cpt`.`schema_version`...
[DEBUG] Lock released for table `cpt`.`schema_version`
[DEBUG] Locking table `cpt`.`schema_version`...
[DEBUG] Lock acquired for table `cpt`.`schema_version`
[DEBUG] Unlocking table `cpt`.`schema_version`...
[DEBUG] Lock released for table `cpt`.`schema_version`
```

If I immediately run this:

```
cat target/classes/db/migration/V2__Triggers.sql | mysql -u root cpt
```

The changes are made as expected.

Any suggestions on what's going on here?  It seems like it should just be throwing this sql directly at the database without trying to parse it, but evidently that is not the case.

Also, and easily as important.  Why am I not receiving a failure message?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you hit an issue with the parser. Please file an issue in the issue tracker with a small sample migration that fails, and I'll try to address it in time for 2.2.